# Play framework + Postgres + Typesafe

Tags: postgresql, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have installed play framework(2.2) with Typesafe Activator, now I want to configure Postgres database.

I found on various posts that from play 2.2 Build.scala is not generated, so I putted this in build.sbt :

```
name := """just-play-java"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
play.Project.playJavaSettings

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100.jdbc4"
)
```

in aplication.conf file I have this section:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/postgres"
db.default.user=postgres
db.default.password=12345678
```

when I hit compile i get this message

```
http://goo.gl/6QrsBS
```

Did I miss some step?

EDIT:
tried true play console to resolve dependencies, there is no recognition of postgre driver
http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2014/04/12/postgreconsole.jpg

How can I include jar in my app?

Answer (score -1):

Adding the postgres driver jar to the `lib` folder and removing the `addind` dependencies in `build.sbt` resolves the problem.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is complete answer, this fixed my problem so I putted it as an answer and not as edit